# Solutions to $\Delta u = u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz} = 0$ that only depend on r

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

> Find all the solutions of $\Delta u = u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz} = 0$ in
>   three dimensions that depend only on $r = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$, the
>   radial variable in polar coordinates. Use the following formula for ∆
>   in spherical polar coordinates  $$u_{rr} + \frac{2}{r}u_r +
>  \frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta \theta} + \frac{1}{r^2}cot(\theta)u_{\theta} +
>  \frac{1}{r^2 (sin\theta)^2}u_{\phi \phi }$$

I'm not sure how to start this problem. I'm thinking that $u_{rr} + \frac{2}{r}u_r = 0$ if $u$ is only to depend on r? Not sure how to continue

Comment: Yeah, that's how you start. If $u$ depends only on $r$, then $u_\theta = u_\phi = 0$. This is an ODE that you can solve a variety of ways.